# Why does ls sort results the way it does?

Tags: ls, sort, gnu, coreutils

I'm just wondering why ls output is sorted the way it is:

```
$ mkdir SortTest<br>
$ cd SortTest<br>
$ for a in {1..34}; do touch filename_$a.txt; done
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_10.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_11.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_12.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_13.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_14.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_15.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_16.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_17.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_18.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_19.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_20.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_21.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_22.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_23.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_24.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_25.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_26.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_27.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_28.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_29.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_30.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_31.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_32.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_33.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_5.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_6.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_7.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_8.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_9.txt
```

I found from other discussions that ls -v will produce a more useful way. But this doesn't change the output I'd expect without any parameter, which is:

(what I would expect, how it doesn't work, but why?)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_10.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_11.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_12.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_13.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_14.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_15.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_16.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_17.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_18.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_19.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_20.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_21.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_22.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_23.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_24.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_25.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_26.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_27.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_28.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_29.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_30.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_31.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_32.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_33.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_34.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_5.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_6.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_7.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_8.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 28 10:49 filename_9.txt
```

I would expect this because the dot "." comes before 0..9 in the ASCII table. And even if sorting should handle the base filename and the extension separately, filename_1 is shorter than filename_10 etc., and should therefore appear first in a sorted string table.

So... why does ls ignore all that and return filename_1.txt AFTER filename_10.txt through filename_19.txt ?

Does anybody happen to know?
And... has it always been like this, or is that one of these modern "improvements"?
If the latter, can I easily switch that off?
Or is it actually a POSIX (or whatever other standard) requirement?

Personally, I don't like it when computers don't follow simple rules, but others - even if these might be considered "more user friendly" by some - after all, they're more surprising.

```
$ ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.30
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the response, that pointed me to a useful explanation.

If I understand it right:

Modern systems tend to have some language specific locale setting - and LC_COLLATE follows, if not manually set to LC_COLLATE=C

That, however, does not only change the sort order to handle upper/lowercase alpha characters in a language specific "natural" way - but at the same time causes ignoration of punctuation for sorting.

Therefore, filename_1.txt gets sorted as if it were filename_1txt - and appears after filename_19txt.

Personally, I think that's pretty unnatural, and an unwanted side effect rather than an improvement. But it's apparently become standard for several years.

Changing /etc/locale.conf to include LC_COLLATE=C should return the old fashioned unsurprising behaviour.

Testing is possible by

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C; ls -l
```

and that indeed returns the listing as I'd expect it.

P.S.: On my Devuan system, /etc/locale.conf does not exist, and although man locale.conf refers to it, and says that systemd would read it early, it did NOT suffice to simply create that file and put a line LC_COLLATE=C into it. Maybe because there is no systemd here :-)

Neither is it possible to set LC_COLLATE via dpkg-reconfigure locales - nor do I find this setting in any existing file below /etc

Instead, I added the line

```
export LC_COLLATE=C
```

into ~/.bashrc and that finally did the trick.

Thanks again for your quick and helpful response.

Comment: `LC_COLLATE=C; ls -l` should probably be `LC_COLLATE=C ls -l` (without the semicolon). Unless `ls` is a builtin command (which usually isn't) or your environment has a variable named `LC_COLLATE` marked for export (which as far as I know is often not the case), `LC_COLLATE=C;` will set a shell variable in the current environment, without making it available to external programs (e.g. `/bin/ls`).